# How to disable scroll in Webview?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Is there a way i can disable scroll in webview?

For instance

```
<WebView rc="https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript- 
openurl" height="300" tap="ontapvw"  ></WebView>
```

Please find the native script playground link attached:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=hh7ITB&v=2

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Linking to external sites for more information is not a good approach. Try to have all relevant information right there in your question please.

Comment: Hi Appreciate your help, will look into it, thanks

Comment: Please note: it is also really bad practice to drop a question to then walk away. People give you feedback, and you should be around to react to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the scroll by accessnig the native WebView and apoplying a native solution (direct access to the native APIs is one of the greatest advantages of nativeScript as this allows you to work with native solutions)

Example for Android
XML

```
<WebView loaded="onWebViewLoaded" src="https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-openurl" height="300" ></WebView>
```

JavaScript

```
function onWebViewLoaded(args) {
  let wv = args.object;
  console.log(wv);

  if(isAndroid) {
      let webViewAndroid = wv.nativeView;
      console.log(webViewAndroid);

      // Hide the scrollbars, but not disable scrolling:
      webViewAndroid.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
      webViewAndroid.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

      // Disable scrolling
      let myListener = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener({
        onTouch: function (view, event) {
          return (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
      })

      webViewAndroid.setOnTouchListener(myListener);
  }

}
exports.onWebViewLoaded = onWebViewLoaded;
```

Playground demo can be found [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=hh7ITB&v=3)

Comment: You will want to gate this with an OS check first, then do the appropriate action on iOS as well.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the code it worked well.. Apologies for the delayed response